# Laravel: Override Package Trait Function

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm using Compoships package to make Laravel support Multi-key relationship but i want to override a trait function in this package.

Here's the current flow:

the main trait im using in my project uses another one in the package which uses another one (the one i want to override)

```
public function addConstraints()
{
    if (static::$constraints) {
        $foreignKey = $this->getForeignKeyName();
        $parentKeyValue = $this->getParentKey();

        //If the foreign key is an array (multi-column relationship), we adjust the query.
        if (is_array($this->foreignKey)) {
            foreach ($this->foreignKey as $index => $key) {

                /*list(, $key) = explode('.', $key);
                $fullKey = $this->getRelated()->getTable().'.'.$key;*/

                $keyPortions = explode('.', $key);
                if(count($keyPortions) === 2)
                    $fullKey = $this->getRelated()->getTable() . '.' . $key;
                else
                    $fullKey = $key;

                $this->query->where($fullKey, '=', $parentKeyValue[$index]);
                $this->query->whereNotNull($fullKey);
            }
        } else {
            $fullKey = $this->getRelated()->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey;
            $this->query->where($fullKey, '=', $parentKeyValue);
            $this->query->whereNotNull($fullKey);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to override it locally but once i deploy the code (composer update happens) i lose my modifications

so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

simple just make a public function with the same name in controller where you use it

its automatcally override

for example

we know in auth folder register controller there is a trait RegistersUSers;
this trait contains a function  authenticate so if we want to override it. just make a public function with the same name

```php
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

   public function authenticate(){

   }
```